# Error jQuery requires a window with a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running a Rails 4.2 app and I am getting the spinning cursor. Found this error. But I don't know how to deal with it. I am using a template. What causes this? what should I be looking for to fix it? I don't even know what code I should post to show here.

Comment: Have you tried googling your error message? There are lots of other questions about it, although it seems that most are related to using jQuery with node.js.

Comment: yes, I had the same results. All with node.js. Didn't help.